# What are the dashes in git? Such as: -a -b -p

Tags: linux, git, bash, shell

I know generally what they do, but where do they come from? Do they have a formal name? I've seen similar letters followed by dashes often in shell commands as well.

I couldn't turn up an answer after some quick searching, since I can't search for "-a" "-b" etc since the dash isn't picked up by search engines.

Edit: I found a search engine to look up things like this: [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are called switches. They are extremely common on the command line. Most open source software (such as git) use libraries like getopt to read these. The format is very predictable:

- -a [VALUE] (for single letter switches)
- --name[=VALUE] (for spelled out switches)

In both of these cases VALUE may or may not be required depending on the switch. In your example they're not used. Reading the man pages or running `command --help` will usually tell you what switches are supported.

Comment: Thank you, I always wondered about the difference between - and -- till yours and jcollado's posts today.

Answer (score 1):

They are frequently called options; programming tools like `getopt` and `popt` parse them in a more or less standard way.  You will run into them all over the place in Unix, such as the standard `ls -l` option to list in "long form" rather than short form.

The point of the `-` is not that it is anything but an arbitrary-but-conventional character that rarely occurs in, for example, at the start of the names of files, or branches, so is relatively easy to distinguish between "behave differently" and "operate on this thing" in the tool.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The dashes mark options to the command. So, `-a` is one option, and `-b` is another option.

The reason there is a dash is so that you and the command know that it is an option. So for example,

```
git commit --amend main.c
```

The dashes before `--amend` makes it clear that `--amend` is an option, whereas `main.c` has no dashes, so it is a regular argument.

And this is the way it is with almost all shell commands. See [a man page](http://www.cs.potsdam.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+git) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what has been explained in other answers, please note that there's a `git help` comand that will provide information about the options for all subcommands.

For example, in the output for `git help commit` you'll see the following:

> OPTIONS
>
> ```
>   -a, --all
>       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not
>       told git about are not affected.
> ```

Comment: Ah, so -- just means that the option is spelled out as a full word. Thanks, I always wondered about that.