# Rvm error: Error running '__rvm_make -j2'

Tags: ruby, rvm

Error running '__rvm_make -j2',
please read /usr/share/rvm/log/1657548775_ruby-2.5.5/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

Comment: Have you read `/usr/share/rvm/log/1657548775_ruby-2.5.5/make.log`? What's in there? What is your operating system and version? Which Ruby version are you trying to install?

Answer (score 8):

After struggling a lot. This worked for me

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm remove x.x.x
rvm install x.x.x -C --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: I thought my installation did not complete so there is no sense in running remove. I was wrong!

Comment: Thanks! It worked on Arch `Kernel: 6.4.11-arch2-1`

Answer (score 6):

**Foreword**: I encountered this problem while trying to install rvm in `WSL2`

Onto to the meat now.

You may encounter newer versions of this error marked by a different end [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324150/what-are-the-dashes-in-git-such-as-a-b-p#:%7E:text=Those%20are%20called,switches%20are%20supported.). I mean, instead of the last switch being strictly -j2, yours might be -j3, j4, j5, or other subsequent ones. Therefore proceed to read below for a possible solution.

Shortly, I suggest two commands to resolve this error. Please do not run the installation suggestion that may appear immediately after running the first command. Instead, just proceed to run the second command.

On pasting the second command, replace **`<version>`** portion with the appropriate ruby version you would like to install. In my case, I wanted to install ruby version 2.7.4, and therefore, I set it as `ruby-2.7.4`

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install ruby-<version> --with-openssl-dir=/usr/share/rvm/usr
```

However, if the above fix fails to remedy the ruby installation problem, you can ensure that `rvm` is added to the user group by running the command below:

```
rvm group add rvm $USER
```

After running the command above, close the Ubuntu app and reopen it. Then proceed to run the command below:

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

Now try reinstalling ruby with the command `rvm install 2.7.4 --default`. If problems persist, run `sudo usermod -a -G rvm $USER` and attempt a reinstall. If that fails, only further research gives you a chance.

**PS**:

Please note that I was making this installation in `Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) Ubuntu` Therefore, if this problem persists in another system like macOS, it may mean that this solution is perhaps not platform agnostic, and thus, the specific solution for such requires further digging.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar error "Error running '__rvm_make -j10'" and solved with  --with-out-ext=fiddle flag.

```
rvm install "ruby-2.7.0" --with-out-ext=fiddle
```

This on M1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem -  Error running "__rvm_make -j4". The bug was the lack of support for OpenSSL 3.0 when used on Ubuntu 22.04. You can try using "rbenv" instead of "rvm", it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this command to solve the issue

```
sudo apt-get install curl git g++ make libssl-dev libreadline-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error trying to install ruby 3.1.3, I've tried doing "rvm pkg install openssl" as said in other replies but it didnt work.

I only managed to finally install it when I checked the "Run command as a login shell" option on the console's settings. You can find that on the "command" options on profile preferences

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with RVM and Ruby 3.3.0 too. Per a blog post called [OpenSSL error installing Ruby 3.3.0](https://johnskinnerportfolio.com/blog/ruby_330_error.html) the answer was:

```
brew install openssl@3
rvm install 3.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)
```